# Camel DefaultMessage cannot be created without CamelContext in version 2.23.0

Tags: java, apache-camel, osgi, camel-cxf

My actual code (Camel 2.10.x) create a new Camel Message to wrap some data (http query) like this:

```
Message message = new DefaultMessage();
message.setHeader(HEADER_QUERY, query);
message.setHeader(HEADER_BRAND, brand);
message.setHeader(HEADER_LIST_ID, listId);
```

And while I am migrating my platform, the version of Camel we use is: 2.23.0 and we can see now the empty constructor is deprecated.
When executing the code, we have the same issue as mentioned in [this post](https://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Problem-after-upgrade-to-Camel-2-20-x-from-2-19-x-td5816400.html) from the official Camel forum.

The good way seems to create the Message by using the Constructor with the CamelContext in parameter like this:

```
Message message = new DefaultMessage(camelContext);
message.setHeader(HEADER_QUERY, query);
message.setHeader(HEADER_BRAND, brand);
message.setHeader(HEADER_LIST_ID, listId);
```

I am in an OSGI context but the code is in a Bean where I have not the `Exchange` nor the original `Message` available.
I am just wondering how can I provide the `CamelContext` to the Message constructor or if there is another way to create `DefaultMessage` without the CamelContext.

Note that I am not in a Camel Route, the Bean is called from a REST interface (I suspect there are some refactoring to clean this up, but we plan to decommission this soon). I am looking for a quick win solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the solution with `Main.getInstance().getOrCreateCamelContext()` seems not working in my context (OSGI): the `Main.getInstance()` always returns null.

But I finally found another way to make it work:

**First Step**

Inject the bundleContext into my Bean:

```
<bean id="myCustomMessageFactory" class="org.mycompany.module.factory.CustomMessageFactory">
    <property name="bundleContext" ref="blueprintBundleContext" />
</bean>
```

The `blueprintBundleContext` is automatically set and does not need to be declared.

**Second step**

from the Bean (Java code):

```
ServiceReference sr = bundleContext.getServiceReference(CamelContext.class);
CamelContext camelContext = (CamelContext) bundleContext.getService(sr);
// and then I can inject the camelContext into the message constructor
Message message = new DefaultMessage(camelContext);
```

It works perfectly in the OSGI landscape.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `org.apache.camel.main.Main` class. It is a singleton, so you can get instance by using `Main.getInstance()` , then you can call `getOrCreateCamelContext()` method to get CamelContext.

Comment: Unfortunately in an OSGI bundle, the `Main.getInstance()` returns null.